# C++ getting integer instead of a float value

Tags: c++

My problem is that when dividing two integers I can't get a float value. 
Here's the code

```
{
    cout << "Kokie skaiciai?" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Atsakymas: " << dalyba(x, y) << endl;
}
```

and the function that i use

```
int dalyba (int x, int y)
{
float z;
z = (float) x / y;
return z;
}
```

so if x = 5 and y = 2 I get an answer 2 instead of 2.5.
Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function returns an `int` instead of a `float`, so the float result is cast back to an integer, and truncated. You may want to change the return value type of your function from `int` to `float`.

Moreover, in modern C++, you may want to use *C++-style casts* like `static_cast<>`.

The following snippet prints `2.5` as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float f(int x, int y) {
    return static_cast<float>(x) / y;
}

int main() {
    cout << f(5, 2) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The return value of your `dalyba` function is an int. This should be a float.

```
float dalyba (int x, int y)
{
    float z;
    z = (float) x / y;
    return z;
}
```

Comment: @user3504402: I tried it and got `2.5`. I get `1075838976` if I take the `float` value `2.5` and interpret it as if it were an `int`. You must be doing something else in the code you're not showing us.